# Proof of $(I-P)(I-tP)=I-P$

Tags: proof-verification, linear-transformations

Sorry, this is my first questions and I don't know how to find the symbols.

Let $V= U \bigoplus W$ be a vector space direct sum of subspaces, and $P$ associated projection onto $U$.

Prove that for any scalar $t$

$(I-P)(I-tP)=I-P$

I tried just multiplying out the LHS but then it just gives me $I-P$ and doesn't prove anything for a scalar $t$.

Comment: If multiplying out the l.h.s. gives $I - P$, you're done.

Comment: What you've done is correct. Since the equation holds, which can be verified by multiplying the lhs out (what you did), it is independent of t and therefore holds for any t.

Comment: (Note that for linear transformations T and S we write (T)(S) to denote the
map which sends v ∈ V to T(S(v)) and kT to denote the map which sends
v ∈ V to kT(v) was part of the question and I didn't use it. That's why I'm a bit apprehensive about my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$(I-P)(I-tP)=I^2-tIP-PI+tP^2$$
Using properties of identity $IX=XI=X$ and projections $P^2=P$, we get
$$I^2-tIP-PI-tP^2=I-tP-P+tP=I-P$$
Since no assumptions or restrictions concerning $t$ were made, this is true for any $t$.